# Moving an existing Nexus 3 blobstore to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, nexus, sonatype

I'm currently migrating a Sonatype Nexus 3 OSS installation that uses a filesystem blobstorage to an EC2 docker installation that will use an S3 bucket as a blobstorage.

Reading the Nexus documentation I've noticed that moving a blobstorage from filesystem to S3 is possible through a feature called 'group blobstorage', but it's currently only available to Nexus PRO users.

Is there any other way to migrate that doesn't require a PRO license?

I've tried manually moving a blobstorage contents (after updating the metadata.properties file with the value `type = s3/1` instead of `type = file/1`), but after setting up the bucket as a S3 blobstorage, the new Nexus installation sees it as empty (it most certainly needs configurations to index it properly).

Comment: How much data do you have and what type or repos ? The easiest way is probably to configure the same repos backed by the S3 blostore then to parse the existing repos on the file blobstore and push the content to the other side. The second easiest solution is to use your credit card if you can afford it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically use the explanation on https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/235816228-Relocating-Blob-Stores
But you need to configure the orientDB/config to use s3 instead of file.

The SQL goes like this for bucket=bucketname with a prefix=blobstorename for a blobstore:

```
UPDATE repository_blobstore MERGE {attributes: {s3: {region: 'eu-central-1', bucket: 'bucketname', prefix: 'blobprefix', expiration: '5', encryption_type: 's3ManagedEncryption'} } } WHERE name='blobstorename'
```

Comment: the only issue i can see is missing blob size

Comment: I think the blob-size will be recalculated when a reconcile task completes a run over the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to upgrade to the enterprise version and move the repositories from file to S3, instead of moving the blob stores around via the grouping option.
After that, you can downgrade to the OSS version by setting the boolean "nexus.loadAsOSS=true" in the /etc/nexus.properties